# Unix timestamp comparisons

Tags: c, unix, timestamp

How do we compare various timestamp in a C program on Unix?

I have to write a pgm which will check a `ctime` of a file and if it is `<` the machine boot time, the file will be removed. I am using `getutxid` to get the `BOOT_TIME` and `stat()` for the file `ctime`. It seems the timestamps returned against these two are in different format. What is the common format and how to convert so that logical comparisons are possible? Such as:

```
if (ctime < boottime)
```

and etc.

Comment: Put your timestamp in a `struct timeval` and use the `timercmp` macro.

Comment: `getutxid` has, as part of the return structure a `struct timeval`, while `stat` returns the simple `time_t`. You can compare the `tv_sec` value to the `time_t` value to determine if the file is newer/older